# jQuery - it takes about 40 second to launch animation. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Thats my code [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mE7gCPjsF9cEeF0twhll)

Basically its simple pagination between few tabs with animation. When I click "next" and move to second page - everything works perfect.

Problem starts after second page, I need to wait about 30-40 seconds before animation of disappearing tabs starts. Just click, it will be mess with tabs, then wait about a minute and you will see what I mean.

Appearing of next page works, even if its in function which should be executed after diappearing of previous page...

SAMPLE CODE:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <article class="employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <div class="more_staff">
        more
      </div>
      <div class="less_staff">
        less
      </div>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <div class="more_staff">
        more
      </div>
      <div class="less_staff">
        less
      </div>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <div class="more_staff">
        more
      </div>
      <div class="less_staff">
        less
      </div>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
      <article class=" employee-article">
      </article>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
article, div.more_staff, div.less_staff {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 10px;
}
article:nth-child(n+10), div.more_staff:nth-child(n+10), div.less_staff:nth-child(n+10) {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $( ".more_staff" ).click(function() {
    that = $(this);
    nextBreakpoint = that.nextAll( ".more_staff" ).first().next();

    that.siblings().add( that ).not( "footer" ).animate({opacity: "0.0"}, 1000, function() {
      console.log("start");
      $( this ).css("display", "none");
      that.nextUntil( nextBreakpoint ).css("display", "block");
      that.nextUntil( nextBreakpoint ).animate({opacity: "1.0"}, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to fadeIn, fadeOut, still dunno why it did not work properly.

```
$( ".more_staff" ).click(function() {
                that = $(this);
                nextBreakpoint = that.nextAll( ".more_staff" ).first().next();
                prevBreakpoint = that.prevAll( ".more_staff" ).first();

                that.prevUntil( prevBreakpoint ).add( that ).not( "footer" ).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    console.log("start");
                    $( this ).css("display", "none");
                    that.nextUntil( nextBreakpoint ).fadeIn(1000);
                });
            });
```